# Number of lines in a file using c

Tags: c, file

I m new to File Handling in C.I am working on a program for counting the number of lines and characters in c.The program is working fine for characters but for lines the o/p is always one less.I have used new line characters for counting the no. of lines.Here is my code:

```
 main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int c,nl=0,nc=0;
    char str[20];
    printf("Enter filename\n");
    scanf("%s",str);
    fp=fopen(str,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        while(1)
        {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
        printf("Enter new filename\n");
        scanf("%s",str);
        fp=fopen(str,"r");
        if(fp!=NULL)
        break;
        }
    }
    c=getc(fp);
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        if(c=='\n')
        nl++;
        nc++;
        c=getc(fp);
    }
    printf("no of lines=%d no of char=%d",nl,nc);
}
```

What is wrong with my implementation?.Is there any other method to count the no. of lines?

Comment: Very tiny (opinion based) stylistic nitpick: the `while(1)` could just be `while(!fp)`.  You could even do it in a do-while loop and not have to repeat `fopen` lines.  `do { scanf(...); fp = fopen(...); } while (!fp);`

Comment: Please take the habit of compiling with all warnings and debugging info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux. At the very least, your `main` is poorly defined (it should return an `int`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your definition of a line. If a file contains only the single character 'a', does it have one line or no lines? By your program's logic, it has zero lines.

You could add, at the end of the `while` loop, outside the closing `}`, this line:

```
if (c != '\n') nl++;
```

That will add an extra line if the last character is not a newline. You should also initialize `c` to zero, otherwise this will cause unpredictable results if the file is empty.

As you can see from the other answers, it's not completely clear what it means to count the number of lines in a file. Make sure you have a very clear understanding of what it is precisely that you are trying to count before you start writing code.

Comment: Check if with an empty file and with a file that ends with a newline. Make sure you get all these cases correct.

Comment: 1) `if (c != '\n') nl++;` does not appear to help as `c` would always be `EOF` after the while loop? 2) Do not think `c = 0;` helps as first use of `c` is `c=getc(fp);`.

Answer (score 3):

The last line of any file does not need to end with a newline `\n` character. Hence your program will report the number of newlines, not the number of "lines" (which is a conventionally defined concept).

Answer (score 3):

**[Edited]**

The final result will be 1 less because you're counting "\n" as the end-of-line, while the last line would not have "\n" as the end of line. It would just find no character. (Thanks for pointing out my error @Basile)

So for the correct answer just incremement the number of lines outside your while loop.

@DavidSchwartz finds this answer inadequate and pointing out the obvious. So for completeness I'll just add: (continued in the [solution by David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079929/1782481)).

Comment: The last line don't contain an `EOF` it is just the result of `getc` when reading failed because the end of file was reached. In other words, `EOF` is not a possible character!

Comment: An empty file has one line?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Technically, yes. One empty line. (By the OP's definition of a line that is.)

Comment: "By the OP's definition of a line that is". I couldn't agree with you more though.

Comment: The OP didn't really specify his definition. He said his code produced a number that was always one less, suggesting he could just add one to it. But I strongly suspect he didn't test any edge cases where his program produces a result that's not one less than the "correct" result. The hard part about solving the problem is defining what it means to count the lines in a file with sufficient precision.

Comment: Didn't really specify? OP: "I have used new line characters for counting the no. of lines."

Just saying.

Comment: @varevarao: That's what he tried, and he discovered it didn't work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, if that's what he tried it's because he has a way defined for counting the lines, it didn't work and that's why the question. If that's his way of counting lines you're right in pointing out a better way, I just pointed out what's the current problem. I upvoted your answer because it was more elaborate (again, I thought that's how SO works). Sorry if you found this terribly inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

The last line is not counted in your program as it is not encountering `\n`..

write the logic which also counts the last line..